# Make a Scrollviewer not vertically scrollable

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

I have a `ScrollViewer` which I don't wish to be scrollable vertically. I have its `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` set to `Hidden`, but I can still scroll with the mouse wheel.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled`, and its content will only be given as much vertical space as exists in the viewport.

A value of `Hidden` still allows the content to extend beyond the viewport, and you can still issue scrolling commands; the scroll bar itself is hidden, but scrolling is not disabled.